# Why is this short snippet ill suited for a multithreaded application?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

As an exercise, I am asked whether or not the following code snippet is good practise when writing a multi threaded application. The answer key says that it is not, without further motivation, but I don't understand why that is.

I thought that the keyword `synchronized` keeps threads from meddling with each other and all the methods are too small for you to worry about starvation.

```
public class myThread{
    private static int a = 0;
    public synchronized void incA(){
        a++;
    }
    public synchronized void decA(){
        a--;
    }
     public synchronized int getA(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

**What is wrong with the above code snippet?**

Comment: super slow, every thread will we waiting extremely long. Imagine n-threads running this in a while(true), they will just waste time.

Comment: True. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Also, why is `a` `static`?

Comment: This rather defeats the entire point of threading, if you work around every variable access to cater for synchronization. Far better to keep threads separate and allow a sensible means of cross-thread communication e.g. using thread safe timers and queues.

Comment: Boris, you make an interesting point. That does seem odd. I got so caught up thinking about threading that I overlooked them setting 'a' static.

Comment: @V.Vocor see my answer - the real reason this code is bad is not because its a bit ugly or a bit slow, but it's because it's plain wrong.

Comment: Accepting the answer ASAP. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your code is **not thread safe**. You have a `static` variable and **instance** methods.

This is not only "*ill suited*", it's **wrong**.

Your methods are `synchronized` on `this` as they are instance methods, this means that each and every instance of your `MyThread` will have it's own lock.